# How to initalise Elixir module with random constant?

Tags: elixir

I know in Elixir I can initiate a module with a random variable like so:

```
defmodule MyMod do
  @word = "test"
end
```

but is it possible to initiate this module with a random word something like

```
defmodule MyMod do
  @words = ["test", "hello", "bye"]
  @word = @words[1]
end
```

or even more random than that and have a function that gets called on initialisation that and does some better random logic to determine the starting word?

Comment: Use Enum.random/1 to obtain a random integer -- see https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1-examples -- then use it as in index into you strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted to clarify the earlier comment in an answer: yes, you can use `Enum.random/1` e.g.

```
defmodule MyMod do
  @words ["test", "hello", "bye"]
  @word Enum.random(@words)
end
```

or you could reference an existing function (e.g. one providing more complex logic). In that case, the function will need to be dynamic, perhaps like:

```
defmodule MyMod do
  f = fn -> 
   # do something
  end

  @foo f.()

  # ...
end
```

OR the called function must be isolated in a different module (because you can't make calls to functions/modules that have not yet been compiled).

In one [recent example](https://github.com/luoken/iso_lang/blob/main/lib/iso_lang/data.ex), I used compile-time functions to build out module data from a CSV file.

In either case, you should understand that the evaluation of this code will occur when the module is *compiled*, not when the code is actually *run*.  This may or may not be what you're looking for: it is not the same as code that gets executed when an instance of an object or class is initialized in the object-oriented paradigm.

*Sidenote:* the module attributes in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) are assigned without the equal sign:

```
- @foo = :bar
+ @foo :bar
```